# Javascript hoisting in blocks such as if/else

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why this displays 'undefined'.

```
'use strict';
console.log(x);

if(true) {
  var x = 'x';
}
```

Will someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What about it do you not understand? Is it working differently from how you expect?

Comment: What else do you expect it to do, throw an error? Use `let` or `const` for that.

Comment: Hoisting also happens in code blocks and if the `if` is removed from the above example, it happens, too.

Comment: @marekful No, the `if` has no bearing on hoisting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: @JLRishe, I guess it does. The if is an internal block, that's why no hoisting within it, but if the assignment is not in an if block, hoisting happens.

Comment: @marekful Hoisting happens regardless of whether the code is in an `if` block.

Comment: @JLRishe i just dont understand why it doesnt get set to 'x'. The condition is true, so it seems like it should be set to x.

Comment: @CTH But that happens after you logged the variable's value?

Comment: @CTH It is being set to `"x"`, but _after_ you log it.

Comment: To avoid confusion: simply start using *let* and *const*.

Comment: Don't know why this question was down-voted, looks like @CTH is simply trying to understand the concept of hoisting.

Answer (score 2):

Hoisting causes the code to behave the same as this:

```
'use strict';
var x;
console.log(x);

if(true) {
  x = 'x';
}
```

So the x is still undefined but it is not an error to use it before the declaration, since it's still declared in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Variable hoisting only moves the *declaration* of the variable to the top of the scope. It doesn't move its *assignment* anywhere.

As others have said, hoisting makes your code equivalent to

```
"use strict";
var x;
console.log(x);

if (true) {
    x = 'x';
}
```

Even after hoisting, `x` is still undefined, because it hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Without hoisting, your code would throw an error due to an undeclared variable. The benefit hoisting provides is that you won't get an error if you reference a variable before it is assigned a value.

Comment: @Nayish No, it doesn't. Yours doesn't have anything resembling the first paragraph or last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Nayish And the reason that my answer was seven (not ten) minutes later than yours was that I was actually waiting for OP to explain what part of the behavior was confusing him/her (and asked him/her for clarification), while you assumed and jumped the gun.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted because it is technically correct and helpful (so +1). Perhaps the downvoter objected to the use of the term "benefit" thinking that failing fast with a `ReferenceError`, as would happen with `let` or `const` would be preferable? Or perhaps someone was picky about the fact that [hoisting doesn't really move anything, but is just an emergent property of the language's execution model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). At any rate the language _behaves as if_ the declaration but not the initialization was moved up.

Comment: @RayToal I think that Nayish downvoted because he thinks my answer is too similar to his (he has since deleted the comment where he accused me of copying him).